# handling data structures in parallel programs

Tags: multithreading, scala

I don't have much experience in writing multi threaded applications so I was wondering if this  is a good way to handle data structures assuming the data structure itself is immutable.
Maybe you could suggest alternatives?

```
class ASyncData[T](var data: T) {
  private val listeners = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[T => Unit]
  def update(f: T => T) {
    Future {
      this synchronized {
        data = f(data)
        listeners.foreach(l => Future(l(data)))
      }
    }
  }
  def get = data
  def onUpdate(f: T => Unit) {
    this synchronized {
      listeners += f
    }
  }
}

val d = new ASyncData(Vector(1,2,3,4))
d.onUpdate {v =>
  println(Thread.currentThread)
  println(v + " updated\n")
}

d.update {v =>
  val newV = v :+ 5
  println(Thread.currentThread)
  println("updating " + v + " to " + newV + "\n")
  newV
}
```

Comment: you might have better luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you have the option to use Scala, then use its built-in concurrency primitives such as the parallel collections, `Future` and Akka, with its actors and other concurrent and distributed computing support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is already implemented in Akka Agents: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/agents.html

The Akka solution has the added advantage that it doesn't use any blocking operations, such as `synchronized`, which reduce the potential concurrency of your code and can slow it down - as per [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

**update from comment**

It *is* possible to queue and serialise operations without blocking.

"Blocking" specifically refers to any code that makes a Java thread enter [either of the `BLOCKED` or `WAITING` states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html).  The techniques for doing this belong to a family known as [non-blocking algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm).

---

Arguably... One of the main benefits in using advanced/specialised libraries such as Akka is that the authors can focus on such logic and keep up with the relevant papers - so you don't have to!

Comment: On the page you linked to it says "At any point in time, at most one send action for each Agent is being executed", which means agents do block in the same way as my implementation.

Comment: I updated the answer to reply to this, so that I could include links.